Do Krashenian-educated language teachers struggle to answer common student questions?
The Krashenian school of language learning emphasizes comprehensible input and values implicit (subconscious) knowledge far above explicit (conscious) knowledge.
Let's imagine a student who has followed a Krashenian language-learning path, and has received large amounts of comprehensible input over the years, and has generally not valued traditional study methods (like textbooks).  They have now reached a high level, and have begun to teach others the language they've learned.
I'm trying to envisage how such a class would proceed.  They'll likely be asked the usual questions like:

What's the meaning of [word]?
What's the difference between [word 1] and [word 2]?
Why is my sentence wrong?
How do I understand the grammar in this sentence?
How do I conclude the answer to this practice question is C?

It seems like the Krashenian student-turned-teacher would struggle answering such explicit-knowledge-based questions, due to a relative lack of experience with explicit knowledge.  If a student asks such questions, it's not helpful to reply "just get more comprehensible input".  Hence...
Question: Do Krashenian-educated language teachers struggle to answer common student questions?
